# windows forms, methods, and buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I am testing out a bank account on windows forms. Something easy to start with. In my `dep_Click` method I have a way where if i click it does the code I wanted in the `aMtBox`. I wanted to expand further and attempted to make a BankAccount class with some properties, etc. I used my `withdrawl_Click` method for this as an attempt to do so. Everything I see looks like it would be okay in a console application, except I have no idea how to call the method in the `withdrawl_Click`; that is, I was it be able to use my code I wrote.

Is the code completely wrong and something is different in windows forms applications? Or is there a concept I am/have not understood. 
Please explain and make this clear to me.

**EDIT**: I updated my code, however it is still giving me an error about needing a return type in the `withDrawl` method near the bottom. Still unsure.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BankAccount a = new BankAccount(iBa, num1);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        decimal iBa = 300.00m; // needs fixed to be more universal
        this.aMtBox.Text = iBa.ToString();
    }


    private void dep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            decimal num1 = 0.00m;
            decimal iBa = 300.00m;
            num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.depBox.Text);
            decimal total = num1 + iBa;
            this.aMtBox.Text = total.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR", "Oops, this isn't good!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    private void withdrawl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public class BankAccount
    {
        decimal iBa;
        decimal num1;
        decimal withT;

        public decimal IBa
        {
            get
            {
                return iBa;
            }
        }
        public decimal Num1
        {
            get
            {
                return num1;
            }
        }
        public decimal Witht
        {
            get
            {
                return withT;
            }
        }

        public withDrawl(decimal n, decimal s )
        {
            iBa = n;
            num1 = s;
            withT = iBa - num1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: To give directions we need to know where you're trying to go. Please explain what your end goal is.

Comment: I see that you have instantiated `BankAccount`, but it doesn't look like you are using it anywhere?  You would need to call your properties in `a` like this `a.IBa` or `a.Num1`.

Comment: I made an edit to this.aMtBox.Text = a.withDrawl;

Comment: @DourHighArch my attempt, or end goal, is for what i click withdrawl it will withdrawl the number I type into the textbox

Comment: I suspect your events aren't wired up.  For the withdrawl button, make sure you have `withdrawl.Click += withdrawl_click;` in your constructor if it isn't already wired up by the designer.

Comment: You `BankAccount` class doesn't have a constructor, but you are passing two parameters to it.  Changing the code in the question is making for a bad question.  All these comments and answers are responding to a moving target.  Focus on one problem and try to solve that.  Ask a new question when a new problem comes up (after trying to solve it yourself).

Comment: @AndrewHeid - as LarsTech mentioned, you are adding complexity that is beyond your level of comprehension (at this time).  You have added two parameters to `BankAccount` (with no constructor), added in `public withDrawl(decimal n, decimal s)` and don't have a `return type` specified... Try the answer I gave below or the one that Jaycee posted and once you understand what is going on there, start expanding your knowledge.

Comment: @Brian I am now. I deleted nearly all of the code and am just going to take this step by step because by looking at what everyone posted.

Comment: @AndrewHeid - use the example below that I posted so you understand how to get at the properties you have.  I will make some adjustments to your code (with comments).

Comment: Your method: public withDrawl(decimal n, decimal s ) has indeed no return type specified. Change it to public void withDrawl(decimal n, decimal s)

Comment: It is very bad to catch all exceptions with `catch`. It is doubly bad to simply show a MessageBox when you catch any exception; for example, that will not work if you want to make a console application. It is triply bad to keep going after you have an exception and not rethrow. It is quadruply bad to use exceptions for control flow statements like validation. It is quintuply bad to discard the exception after catching it. It is sextuply bad to show meaningless error messages like “Oops, this isn't good!”. Your code should not be using `catch` at all.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are [instantiating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd460654.aspx#InstantiatingClasses) your second class, `BankAccount` with this line:

```
BankAccount a = new BankAccount();
```

But, you aren't using it anywhere.  Based on what you have said in your original post, to get to the properties in your second class, you would call them like this:

```
a.IBa;
a.Num1;
a.withDrawl;
```

Below is a VERY simplistic example:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         string aValue = String.Empty;
         Something a = new Something();
         a.SomeThingElse = aValue;
      }
   }

   public class Something
   {
      public string SomeThingElse
      {
         get { return SomeThingElse; }
         set { SomeThingElse = value; }
      }
   }
}
```

In the example above, you can see that I am instantiating my new class `public class Something` in the `button1_Click` event, then calling the property within it by using `a.SomethingElse = aValue`, which is a `string` I have defined in the initial class.  In this case, `aValue=""` because it was initialized to `String.Empty`, which is '""'.

Also, on a side note, you may want to set the abstraction level on your second class to `public`, because without declaring it `public`, it will default to `private` (which would not cause issues in this case - it's just something to keep in mind).

I am adding in another example - this one using some of the code you have provided:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void dep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        try
        {
            decimal newBalance;
            BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount();  // Instantiate your class.
            bankAccount.DepositAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(depAmt.Text); 
            newBalance = (Convert.ToDecimal(currentBalance.Text)) + bankAccount.DepositAmount;
            currentBalance.Text = newBalance.ToString();
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR", "Oops, this isn't good!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

public class BankAccount
{
    decimal depositAmount;

    public decimal DepositAmount
    {
        get { return depositAmount; }
        set { depositAmount = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for flagging, comment has been removed, but next time, please don't feed the trolls. Just silently flag the post. It **will** get deleted.

Comment: You got it Johan.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

```
private void withdrawl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.aMtBox.Text = a.withDrawl().ToString();
}
```

This will get it to compile - it passes the value 300 from the WithDrawl() method into your aMtBox textbox. Entering a value into the depBox textbox say 50, then clicking the dep button will result in a value of 350 in the aMtBox textbox.

Also, if you click the buttons named withdrawl and dep and nothing happens: try opening the form in the designer and double clicking each button. You should land in the withdrawl_Click, dep_Click event handlers.

EDIT:
In response to Withdrawl method return type error:

```
public decimal withDrawl(decimal n, decimal s )
{
    iBa = n;
    num1 = s;
    withT = iBa - num1;
    return withT;
}
```